# Asp .Net Core 2 + SignalR (1.0.0-alpha2-27025) + /signalr/negotiate 404 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I add SignalR to ASP .Net Core 2 app

**packages**

- *"Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0"*
- *"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.0.0-alpha2-27025"*
- *"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="1.0.0-alpha2-27025"*
- *"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core" Version="1.0.0-alpha2-27025"*
- *"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common" Version="1.0.0-alpha2-27025"*
- *"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core" Version="1.0.0-alpha2-27025"*

```cs
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalRCore();
    services.AddSignalR();
}
```

and

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<ManageHub>("manageHub");
    });
}
```

**url:port/signalr**, **url:port/signalr/negotiate...** return 404

**url:port/manageHub** return 400 with "Connection ID required"

I not found .MapSignalR()

How use SignalR in ASP .Net Core?

Comment: have you tried testing it using a client side code? I guess the signalr client libraries would take care of the clientID etc

Comment: Man you are keen tackling an alpha. I'm hanging out for the team to get the core version running too. I'll be interested to see if anyone is keen to post anything this early.

Comment: OrdinaryOrange yes I too was scared of the alpha and created an .net framework website just for signalr. But at least the set up should still work, or they wouldn't have released it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be using the old client. SignalR for ASP.NET Core does not use the `/negotiate` endpoint anymore. The new SignalR server is not compatible with old client and the new clients are not compatible with the old SignalR server. Take a look at the [announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/) and [samples](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Samples)

Comment: What about ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Does not make any difference - MVC is built on top on Asp.NET/Asp.NET Core.

Comment: Could you pls have a look at [SignalR “Access to XMLHttpRequest …” error in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58027442/signalr-access-to-xmlhttprequest-error-in-asp-net-mvc)? Regards.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, make sure you installed the last official version of [SignalR for ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR/1.0.0-alpha1-final)

Second follow that link [How to get SignalR Working in ASP.NET Core 2](https://github.com/davidfowl/SignalRCoreAlphaSample)

Comment: What about ASP.NET MVC?