# Ember 2 Web App using SignalrR from .Net Core 3 API

Tags: javascript, .net-core, ember.js, signalr, .net-core-3.0

We have an ember version 2.18 web application, which talks to a .Net Core 3 api. But we have been trying to implement Signalr, with the api as the signalr server and the ember app as the signalr client. I have got the api working with a mockup Asp.Net website, so it does work.

But we are having issues with ember and there appears to be a significant lack of new articles on this. The only thing we can find seems to point to be using the old signalr, where it calls the negotiate endpoint, which as stated in this answer: [Asp .Net Core 2 + SignalR (1.0.0-alpha2-27025) + /signalr/negotiate 404 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264982/asp-net-core-2-signalr-1-0-0-alpha2-27025-signalr-negotiate-404-error) will not work.

Does anyone have any solutions or links on how to set this up the latest SignalR with ember 2 and a .Net Core 3 api?